# Wordpress. Написание модуля для импорта данных в List

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

С чего начать и какую литературу пересмотреть, чтобы написать свой модуль для импорта csv/xml в List? Хочу написать, [что-то похожее](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/). Опыта разработки под WordPress нету, но есть опыт разработки на PHP.

Comment: Конкретнее, если можно. Что такое List? При чем тут WP? Что и откуда вы будете импортировать?

Comment: Нужно написать что-то похожее [https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/), но для конкретной задачи. Как пример имортировать заявления на продажу машин в List (Car)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Подскажите с чего начать и какую литературу пересмотреть, чтобы
>   написать свой модуль для импорта csv/xml

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Filesystem_API
https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_API